# Google Play console Warning : unknow validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_ICON_NOT_UNIFORM

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

When I tried to upload a bundle to the Alpha channel on the Google Play console it shows to me this warning:
[image]

The warning is shown after uploading `mapping` and `native-debug-symbols` files.

Comment: Does your code anywhere has this: VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_ICON_NOT_UNIFORM string?

Comment: no, I searched in the whole project and didn't find anything

Comment: it shows after uploading mapping and native-debug-symbols files

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: Received the same warning today. Cannot find any reference material to fix the issue. But I was still able to push my app out. So hopefully in a few days we'll know what this is about.

Comment: Same problem here. Soon we'll know more about this.

Comment: I also got that today, this question is the only reference on internet so far

Comment: I knew this warning new, we pray to not impact us

Comment: did you find a answer ? i am getting the same warning.

Comment: No there is no answer until now

Comment: Just got this last apk upload. New and we have not implemented any new icons.  Google check must have changed something on their console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the above warning by replacing the app icon (Playstore Icon) from the new Google Play Console>Main Store Listing>App icon based on the new guidelines introduced by Google https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications
To export the new Play Store Icon, i followed the below link https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio
(Image Asset Studio places the icons in the proper locations in the res/mipmap-density/ directories. **It also creates a 512 x 512 pixel image that's appropriate for the Google Play store.**)

1. From Android Studio right click on the folder res>New>Image Asset
2. Generate the New Play Store Icon from the "Configure Image Asset" popup by selecting the Icon Type as Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy) if your app supports Android 8.0 (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#create-adaptive) or select Launcher Icons (Legacy Only) if your app supports versions no higher than Android 7.1 (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#create-legacy)
3. Click Next and a new Popup appears to Confirm where to export the new Play Store icon (**ic_launcher-playstore.png**) (512x512).
4. Click Finish and upload the new exported Play Store icon in Google Play Console>Main Store Listing>App Icon and the warning now is gone.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a non uniform icon shape of your app:

https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications

You can change your icon according to the new design specifications to remove this warning.

Comment: No, I don't think this is the issue because it didn't show before with same icon

Comment: @MohammadSommakia The standard changed

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Google Play Console > "Main Store Listing" and see if your App Icon is meeting their standards.
2. Upload/replace with new App Icon 512px by 512px

For me this was the issue...

[image]