# VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_ICON_NOT_UNIFORM problems

Tags: android, google-play, publish, google-play-console

When i update my app in google play publish web site , I saw some warning

This warning VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_ICON_NOT_UNIFORM

Is there any trouble for my app in google play store?

Thanks for answer[image]

Comment: Many people are seeing this warning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354836/google-play-console-warning-unknow-validation-validate-app-message-icon-not-un .

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Google Play Console > "Main Store Listing" and see if your App Icon is meeting their standards.
2. Upload/replace with new App Icon 512px by 512px

For be this was the issue (Attached image)

[image]