# Getting VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_ICON_NOT_UNIFORM warning in Google Play Console

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

I am getting this warning **Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_ICON_NOT_UNIFORM** when I tried to update my app in Google Play Console.

I have already looked into this link: [Google Play console Warning : unknow validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_ICON_NOT_UNIFORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354836/google-play-console-warning-unknow-validation-validate-app-message-icon-not-un).

Does anyone know why I am getting this warning? OR Any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See new styling guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354836/google-play-console-warning-unknow-validation-validate-app-message-icon-not-un

Comment: Thanks @Vijay, I had already looked into that.

Comment: have you tried this solution @Shambhavi ?